# QT to build app in ubuntu, based on web app with notifications

Tags: qt, ubuntu, browser, notifications

I want to build an app for ubuntu to work with some existent web application as with separate application and status bar notifications.

It will be just simple web browser window and the web app loaded. I know how to do this.

But i want to make my app to work with notifications. I want to have tray icon for the app and if new message appears in web app then i will show special marker on tray icon.
To make this work i need to know what is going on in the web browser component of my app.

Is there a way or some component for Qt to filter traffic from web browser component?
I can catch ajax requests from web app , filter and understand when to show notification in tray icon.

I want to use Qt but maybe there is something better?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Inject your javascript and objects to web page:
[The Qt WebKit Bridge](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebkit-bridge.html)

I think in your injected javascript you can track changes, catch events e.t.c and notify host application.